# Trying to get property of non-object in while looping prepare statement result

Tags: php

i am new in PHP, and I am trying to execute this function to select number of rows from my database table, but i don't understand why I got this error

> **Notice:** Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Twitter/security/access.php on
>   line 322

line 322 is looping the result

```
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $returnArray[] = $row;
        }
```

here is the full code, What went wrong in here? :(

```
function selectPosts($id) {


        // declare array to store selected information
        $returnArray = array();

        // sql JOIN
        $sql = "SELECT posts.id,
        posts.uuid,
        posts.text,
        posts.path,
        posts.date,
        users.id,
        users.username,
        users.fullname,
        users.email,
        users.ava
        FROM Twitter.posts JOIN Twitter.users ON
        posts.id = $id AND users.id = $id ORDER by date DESC";

        // prepare to be executed
        $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

        // error ocured
        if (!$statement) {
            throw new Exception($statement->error);
        }

        // execute sql
        $statement->execute();

        // result we got in execution
        $result = $statement->get_result();

        // each time append to $returnArray new row one by one when it is found
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $returnArray[] = $row;
        }

        return $returnArray;

    }
```

Comment: check $result it may be null

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, use prepared statements https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: remove dots from this line
FROM Twitter posts JOIN Twitter users ON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement can't be executed / failed, so the `$result` object is not available. You can use the following to make sure you get a result:

```
function selectPosts($id) {

    // declare array to store selected information
    $returnArray = array();

    // sql JOIN
    $sql = "SELECT posts.id,
    posts.uuid,
    posts.text,
    posts.path,
    posts.date,
    users.id,
    users.username,
    users.fullname,
    users.email,
    users.ava
    FROM Twitter.posts JOIN Twitter.users ON
    posts.id = ? AND users.id = ? ORDER by date DESC";

    // prepare to be executed
    $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bind_param('ii', $id, $id);

    // error ocured
    if (!$statement) {
        throw new Exception($statement->error);
    }

    // execute sql
    if (!$statement->execute()) {
        //execute fails
    }

    // result we got in execution
    $result = $statement->get_result();

    if ($result === false && ($statement->errno > 0 || $this->conn->errno)) {
        //result not available
    }

    // each time append to $returnArray new row one by one when it is found
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $returnArray[] = $row;
    }

    return $returnArray;

}
```

Make also sure to use the prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to get the error from the statement you've just checked is false.  You need to get the error from the connection in this case..
Instead of

```
if (!$statement) {
    throw new Exception($statement->error);
}
```

you need...

```
if (!$statement) {
    throw new Exception($this->conn->error);
}
```

You should also check when executing that this has worked...

```
if ( !$statement->execute() ) {
    throw new Exception($statement->error);
}
```